# PostgreSQL update if condition is true, but return id based on another condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Apologies if I'm missing something, but I had a bit of a search, and can't find an obvious answer. I have a system where multiple workers share a postgres table, and these workers need to update some rows based on an ID to say that some operation has been completed. As such it's very plausible that two workers will try and update the same rows.

A simplified version of my table looks like this with the three fields being an int, a bool and a timestamp respectively:

```
+----+-------+--------------------------+
| id | done  |      done_timestamp      |
+----+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | false | null                     |
|  2 | false | null                     |
|  3 | true  | 2020-11-24T21:23:04.008Z |
+----+-------+--------------------------+
```

I have an update function which I want to use to update all rows that are passed in, but not any that are already marked as done. It looks like this:

```psql
UPDATE operations AS o
SET done = TRUE,
done_timestamp = o2.done_timestamp
FROM (VALUES (1, NOW()), (2, NOW()), (3, NOW())) AS o2(id, done_timestamp)
WHERE o2.id = o.id AND NOT o.done;
```

So far so good. I'm updating 2 out of the three rows, and I'm not updating the 3rd because something has already done that, and I don't want to update the timestamp there. Here's what I get in my table:

```
+----+------+--------------------------+
| id | done |      done_timestamp      |
+----+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | true | 2020-11-24T21:38:29.871Z |
|  2 | true | 2020-11-24T21:38:29.871Z |
|  3 | true | 2020-11-24T21:23:04.008Z |
+----+------+--------------------------+
```

The final piece of the puzzle though is that I want to return all IDs that have been updated, so that I can perform some error checking. My first thought was to add a `RETURNING` statement, but  by doing this, I'm only returning the ids that this query has updated, not all of the rows that are done. The query is as follows:

```psql
UPDATE operations AS o
SET done = TRUE,
done_timestamp = o2.done_timestamp
FROM (VALUES (1, NOW()), (2, NOW()), (3, NOW())) AS o2(id, done_timestamp)
WHERE o2.id = o.id AND NOT o.done
RETURNING o.id;
```

Does anyone have a good way of returning **all** of the ids of rows that match the ids that I'm passing in, and have also been marked as done, not just the ones that have been specifically updated in my update query?

Thanks in advance,
F

Comment: `psql` is the Postgres command line client, it really has nothing to do with question. You want to know "Postgresql update if condition is ...". Please change title to make this question clearer.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I'm new to Postgres and thought that `psql` was simply a shortening to make it less verbose. Have updated.

Comment: Thanks. Postgres would be the "official" short version of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell, you're going to need to trick your server to do that. Make it think there was an update when there wasn't, by moving your boolean check into a CASE statement; if `done = TRUE` already, set it to the same timestamp that already existed.

Note: this causes unnecessary UPDATES against the table, and will make for a slower query, but it doesn't look like any kind of MERGE is supported by Postgres that will return the ID's for you like it would in some other DB's.

```sql
UPDATE operations AS o
SET done_ts = case when done = false then o2.done_ts else o.done_ts end,
    done = TRUE
FROM (VALUES (1, NOW()), (2, NOW()), (3, NOW())) AS o2(id, done_ts)
WHERE o2.id = o.id 
RETURNING o.id;
```

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that would work, although I have to admit I was hoping that there was a more elegant solution that wouldn’t have to update those rows. Not least because in the actual system, there are a lot more columns that I’d have to do similar stuff with.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested on your data, but a possible solution using [CTE]s(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH):

```
WITH val(id, done_timestamp) AS 
        (VALUES (1, NOW()), (2, NOW()), (3, NOW())) , 
updated AS 
    (UPDATE operations AS o
        SET done = TRUE, done_timestamp = val.done_timestamp
    WHERE val.id = o.id AND NOT o.done) 
SELECT id FROM val;
```

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but wouldn’t this solution also return ids even if they aren’t in the table?

Comment: Then in the `SELECT` join against `operations` with whatever filter logic is appropriate.